# Should I be calling Dispose() after every usage of FindViewById

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

To prevent any memory leaks in Android Xamarin, should I be calling Dispose() after usage of FindViewById?

An example:

```
void SetTextSomewhereInMyView()
{
var myTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resouce.Id.myTextView);
myTextView.Text = "This is my Text View";

// Should I be calling dispose now? or is it OK not to call dispose?
myTextView.Dispose(); // ?
}
```

I haven't seen Dispose being called that much in Xamarin examples but then I read on a few places that this would be a good practise. What would be the final word on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FindViewById is an expensive call you should not do that often. Instead save the reference at an field and dispose that instance at OnDestroy or OnTrimMemory.

If you need this view only once then dispose it right after usage.

Comment: I would like to add to this that consecutive calls to `FindViewById` for the same view will often return the same reference. If you have disposed of that reference and another `FindViewById` returns that same reference somewhere else in the code you'll get an exception for using a disposed object. I suggest therefore not disposing the object if there is any chance you'll use it again, and indeed cache it if you use it again for sure. If regular GC doesn't clean it up in time, do it yourself in `OnDestroy`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be more expensive to call `FindViewById` every time you need it than the overhead of not calling `Dispose`. My method would be lazy load my views like this:

```
private TextView _myTextView;
public TextView MyTextView
{
    get
    {
       return _myTextView?? (_myTextView= FindViewById<TextView>(Resouce.Id.myTextView));
    }
}

void SetTextSomewhereInMyView()
{
   MyTextView.Text = "This is my Text View";

}
```

Therefore `FindViewById` is only called when needed and the reference to the view is then cached for later.

**In Short:**

If you would like to use the `TextView` again you and you have `Disposed` of it would have to call `FindViewById` Which is an expensive operation. However if you are setting a `TextView's Text` value with no intention of ever needing a reference to that TextView again it is good practice to call `Dispose`

Comment: Hey, yes, I get that, I do keep values in local fields but my question is more if it's a good practise to call dispose every-time I get a reference from FindViewById.

Comment: @JakubHolovsky If you keep the values in local fields and call `Dispose()` on it it will get rid the cached value. Meaning if you would like to get that `TextView` again you would have to call `FindViewById` Which is an expensive operation. However if you are setting a `TextView's Text` value with no intention of ever needing a reference to that `TextView` again it is good practice to call `Dispose`